# Qt 5.6 - Return 2 ints from a custom QDialog

Tags: c++, qt

My problem is: I have subclassed QDialog to get a dialog box that has 2 spinboxes, an ok and a cancel button. This new class is named MapCharacteristicsInputDialog.

Now, when I click a button on my main window, I'd like a dialog of this class to pop out, and then get the values from the spinboxes when it's closed using the Ok button. How can I do this ?

Code that triggers the pop out of the dialog:

```
void MainWindow::on_newMapButton_clicked(){
    MapCharacteristicsInputDialog* dialog = new MapCharacteristicsInputDialog();
    dialog->exec();
}
```

Comment: Use a [QPair](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qpair.html)?

Comment: Are you sure you want to dynamically allocate an instance of the class? Because in C++ you don't have to use `new` to create instances, instead doing that could lead to memory leaks if you don't `delete` the memory you allocated (which you don't seem to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you should check what [the `exec` function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#exec) returns.

Then the simple way is to have two access-function in your `MapCharacteristicsInputDialog` class to get the values of the spinner. once `exec` returns.

Comment: Thanks ! I used `int result = dialog->exec();` and then checked
`if (result == Qt::Accepted){//the getters here}`
Works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `signals` to transmit the values of the spinboxes along with their titles, and then connect those `signals` to the `slots` of whatever object that will be requiring the data.

Read more [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)